# Bash: using getops for this specific use

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would need my bash scrip to work **either with**:

> No arguments

```
./script.sh
```

> Path argument (classic argument, will saved as var to var=$1)

```
./script.sh /root/home/dir/
```

> With switch -a (with it's own argument)

```
./script.sh -a picture.jpeg
```

> Or both combined

```
./script.sh -a picture.jpeg /root/home/dir/
```

I have something like this:

```
while getopts ":a:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    a)
      I_ARGUMENT=$OPTARG
      echo "A ARGUMENT IS: $OPTARG"
      ;;
    :)
      echo "-a requires argument"
      ;;          
  esac
done
```

And then something like this for the path argument:

```
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
    :
else
PATH="$1"
fi
```

Which obviously doesn't work well (at all) together. Could you help me to combine this two things? Thank you.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but your usecase looks like the first example given in "Small getopts Tutorial" ( http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial )

Comment: if you execute `./script.sh -a picture.jpeg /root/home/dir/` the `$1` will be `-a` so in that case if you want to get the path you should use `$3`

Comment: @Matthias I will look into that, I mean I did already before and didn't really get it but I guess I will have to read that couple of times more, but thanks

Comment: @ClaudioM Yeah, but those arguments are not dependable on each other, so the number is not clear in every type of use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this

```
pathToHomeSlashDir=~/dir/ #default value will be home/dir/
if [ $# -gt 0 ]
then
    while [ $# -gt 0 ]
    do
        case "$1" in
            -a)
                if [ $# -gt 1 ]
                then
                    image="$2"
                    shift
                else
                    echo "Please insert -a argument"
                    exit
                fi
                ;;
            *)
                pathToHomeSlashDir="$1"
                ;;
        esac
        shift
    done
fi
```

You'd just need to handle the variables then

Comment: @ClaudioM sorry, but it's working for me.. what error are you getting?

Comment: @A.Marques it kinda works... only, in case of
`./script.sh -a picture.jpeg` how do you define default value of PATH? (when not specified, default value is cwd)

Comment: @toddddos edited my answer to define a default value for PATH and changed its name, cause you shouldn't use PATH as a variable name

Comment: @A.Marques ok, now it works perfectly.. it's exactly what I wanted and it works in bash.